# Can use a text string within Sentonbehalfofname?

Tags: excel, outlook, vba

I would like to send an email using VBA from my account, but have it appear that was sent from a different user. Is there a way to use Sentonbehalfofname so that you can include whatever text string you'd like without having access rights?

```
Set outlookapp = CreateObject("outlook.application")
msg = "Enter Message here"
subject = "Enter subject here"
Set item = outlookapp.createitem(0)

With item
.Sentonbehalfofname = "Yogi Bear"
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

No, Exchange Server will resolve that name to a mailbox and check if you have the right to send on behalf of that mailbox.

If you are using an SMTP server, you might be able to specify an arbitrary name, but that only works for some SMTP servers, it will not work for Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

```
.From = """Your string""  < sender@email.com>"
```