# SentOnBehalfOf not working in Excel 2010 VBA Code

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I am working on a VBA script for mailing through Outlook in Excel 2010.  Everything runs fine with one exception: the .SentOnBehalfofName line will not work.  Here is the complete code

```
 Sub Mail()
' Working in Office 2010-2013
    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strbody As String ' This is for the Body of the email
    Dim signature As String ' This is for the email signature

On Error Resume Next

'Set OutMail = Nothing
'Set OutApp = Nothing


Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = Sheets("Mail")
strbody = sh.Range("C9").Value


Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OutMail ' This inserts the email signature
        .Display
    End With
       signature = OutMail.HTMLBody

With OutMail
    '.Display
    .To = sh.Range("C5")
    .CC = sh.Range("C6")
    .BCC = sh.Range("C7")
    .Subject = sh.Range("C8").Value
    .HTMLBody = "<br>" & strbody & fncRangeToHtml(sh.Range("C13").Value, sh.Range("C14").Value) & signature
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = sh.Range("C4").Value
    .Display

End With

On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

 End Sub
```

If I remove this section the .SentOnBehalfOf works, but I lose my signature line:

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OutMail ' This inserts the email signature
        .Display
    End With
       signature = OutMail.HTMLBody
```

If I put this back in the code, I get my signature line back, but I lose my ability to send on behalf of another party.

I'm looking for a solution that allows me to do both.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800468/can-use-a-text-string-within-sentonbehalfofname) , maybe your string is off.

Comment: Did you check that the string in cell C4 correctly resolves to a name?

Comment: I did, and it does.  I found a solution I will post next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution.  I needed to move the .SentOnBehalfOfName to the first statement in the WITH Command, then .Display immediately after that.  I replace the string for signature line with .HTMLBody to pull in the signature line.  Code runs fine now!

I don't know why the statements need to be in this order, but it works.......

```
Sub Mail()
' Working in Office 2010-2013
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim strbody As String ' This is for the Body of the email

On Error Resume Next

'Set OutMail = Nothing
'Set OutApp = Nothing

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = Sheets("Mail")
strbody = sh.Range("C9").Value


Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
With OutMail
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = sh.Range("C4")
    .Display
    .To = sh.Range("C5")
    .CC = sh.Range("C6")
    .BCC = sh.Range("C7")
    .Subject = sh.Range("C8").Value
    .HTMLBody = "<br>" & strbody & fncRangeToHtml(sh.Range("C13").Value, sh.Range("C14").Value) & .HTMLBody

End With

On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```