# VBA: Change Outlook "From" and font size

Tags: vba, excel, fonts, outlook

I'm trying to send an Outlook email from VBA Excel.  I've got everything declared correctly, as far as I can tell.  I'm having issues with changing the sender and the font size.

The from is a secondary email, also on Outlook, which I have access to.
The font issue is that I can't seem to achieve font size 11 when using the below code.

---

**Sender:**

```
With OutMail
        .Display
        .Sender = "someone@example.com"
        '.SentOnBehalfOfName = "someoneelse@example.com"
        .To = origintext
        .Subject = "Location Verification"

        .BodyFormat = 2 'olFormatHTML
        .HTMLBody = fMsg & fMsg2 & fMsg3 & signature
        '.Body = signature

        .Display
End With
```

Where `fMsg`, `fMsg2`, and `fMsg3` are strings. The signature is declared earlier in the code with:

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
OutMail.Display
signature = OutMail.HTMLBody
```

I do this to get the signature as it seems to be impossible to use something such as `OutMail.Signature = *Signature1*`.

I understand there is an `OutMail.SentOnBehalfOf = hello@world.com` but that does not seem to work with `OutMail.BodyFormat = 2` which sets the body to HTML format.

---

**Font:**

An example of my HTML body is as follows:

```
fMsg = "<p><font face = ""Calibri(Body)"" font size=""3"" color=""black"">Hello,</font></p>"
```

However, the issue that comes with this is `font size=""3""` does not actually give font size 3, it gives font size 10.  I'm trying to get to 11.  `font size=""4""` produces size 13.5.

---

**TL;DR:**

What's the VBA code to send an Outlook email from my second email account?

What's the VBA code to get font size 11 using HTML format?

Comment: @JasonMArcher  Thanks for the save!  Looks like I missed a few things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SentOnBehalfOfName is a little tricky. See here where it works when it precedes Display. [SentOnBehalfOf not working in Excel 2010 VBA Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26432256/sentonbehalfof-not-working-in-excel-2010-vba-code)

You can use "style=font-size:11pt" as described here [Change HTML email body font type and size in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22200910/change-html-email-body-font-type-and-size-in-vba)

Answer (score 0):

The [SendUsingAccount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869311(v=office.15).aspx) property of the MailItem class allows to set an Account object that represents the account under which the MailItem is to be sent. For example:

```
 Sub SendUsingAccount() 
  Dim oAccount As Outlook.account  
  For Each oAccount In Application.Session.Accounts 
  If oAccount.AccountType = olPop3 Then  
   Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem  
   Set oMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)  
   oMail.Subject = "Sent using POP3 Account"  
   oMail.Recipients.Add ("someone@example.com")  
   oMail.Recipients.ResolveAll  
   oMail.SendUsingAccount = oAccount  
   oMail.Send  
  End If  
 Next  
End Sub
```

Try to use the Word object model to change the font size in emails. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: My line `OutMail.SendUsingAccount = "myname@account.com"` does seem to be doing what it should.